# How can I add the name of a list element as the title of a scatterplot from ggplot2?

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, purrr

I have a large list called big_list2 that has six lists in it. Each list has the name of a transcript I am interested in. I generate a scatterplot for each list inside big_list2. I would like to use the name of each list (i.e., the name of the transcript) as the title of the scatterplot.

This is big_list2:

```
> dput(big_list2)
list(Zm00001eb000210_T001_1 = structure(list(uORF = c("Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000210_T001_1", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T001_1"), sample = c("1Leaf1", "1Leaf2", "1Root1", 
"1Root2", "3Leaf1", "3Leaf2", "Ear1", "Ear2", "Ear5mm_1", "Ear5mm_2", 
"Embryo15_1", "Embryo15_2", "Embryo20_1", "Embryo20_2", "Endosperm15_1", 
"Endosperm15_2", "Endosperm20_1", "Endosperm20_2", "Inflorescence1", 
"Inflorescence2", "Kernel1", "Kernel2", "Leaf1", "Leaf2", "Root1", 
"Root2", "Root6DAS_1", "Root6DAS_2", "SAM_V1_1", "SAM_V1_2", 
"SAM_V3_1", "SAM_V3_2", "Seedling1", "Seedling2", "Seedling6DAS1", 
"Seedling6DAS2", "Stem1", "Stem2", "Tassel1", "Tassel2", "Tassel1cm1", 
"Tassel1cm2", "TopLeaf1", "TopLeaf2"), uORF.counts = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11.4347855154007, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 33.3338244380922, 0, 0, 0, 361.143298701066, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 73.9301306725009, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    mORF.counts = c(0, 0, 0, 0.343544763388441, 0, 0, 0.0760966486956441, 
    0.0989407598144533, 0.104551293297911, 0.685769475329068, 
    0.438970125615888, 0.183828153543562, 0.0492631332412111, 
    0, 0.284960191689523, 0.414532526807716, 0.755067264729411, 
    0.415271301202561, 0.962658543958137, 0.253064810686685, 
    0, 0.288839940994747, 0, 0, 0.075966119209846, 0, 0, 0.0859279434500381, 
    0.111113029385815, 0.337618989220899, 0.19244911952294, 0.885797519484353, 
    0.0577068647184253, 1.0274385206843, 0.170047092744869, 0.200225443771896, 
    0.07452871786933, 0, 0.424885586034637, 0.149978447560262, 
    0.291650426819245, 0.150791469374745, 0.185266040760669, 
    0)), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), Zm00001eb000210_T002_9 = structure(list(uORF = c("Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", "Zm00001eb000210_T002_9", 
"Zm00001eb000210_T002_9"), sample = c("1Leaf1", "1Leaf2", "1Root1", 
"1Root2", "3Leaf1", "3Leaf2", "Ear1", "Ear2", "Ear5mm_1", "Ear5mm_2", 
"Embryo15_1", "Embryo15_2", "Embryo20_1", "Embryo20_2", "Endosperm15_1", 
"Endosperm15_2", "Endosperm20_1", "Endosperm20_2", "Inflorescence1", 
"Inflorescence2", "Kernel1", "Kernel2", "Leaf1", "Leaf2", "Root1", 
"Root2", "Root6DAS_1", "Root6DAS_2", "SAM_V1_1", "SAM_V1_2", 
"SAM_V3_1", "SAM_V3_2", "Seedling1", "Seedling2", "Seedling6DAS1", 
"Seedling6DAS2", "Stem1", "Stem2", "Tassel1", "Tassel2", "Tassel1cm1", 
"Tassel1cm2", "TopLeaf1", "TopLeaf2"), uORF.counts = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11.4347855154007, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 33.3338244380922, 0, 0, 0, 361.143298701066, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 73.9301306725009, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    mORF.counts = c(0, 0, 0, 0.365321371340932, 0, 0, 0.0809202613998489, 
    0.105212414534932, 0.111178588392205, 0.72923901584173, 0.466795554343452, 
    0.19548064852228, 0.0523858236543152, 0, 0.303023242091701, 
    0.440808905556183, 0.802929452001876, 0.441594509366221, 
    1.02367952270084, 0.172996764026799, 0, 0.307148920861081, 
    0, 0, 0.0807814579138581, 0, 0, 0.0913747420512427, 0.118156259663823, 
    0.239346649553322, 0.204648080104722, 0.941946433287732, 
    0.0613647861978446, 1.09256577117576, 0.180826034142905, 
    0.212917329825197, 0.0792529426085881, 0, 0.395340946240699, 
    0.159485278115995, 0.310137557699591, 0.160349835739483, 
    0.197009680502875, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), Zm00001eb000470_T001_1 = structure(list(
    uORF = c("Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_1"
    ), sample = c("1Leaf1", "1Leaf2", "1Root1", "1Root2", "3Leaf1", 
    "3Leaf2", "Ear1", "Ear2", "Ear5mm_1", "Ear5mm_2", "Embryo15_1", 
    "Embryo15_2", "Embryo20_1", "Embryo20_2", "Endosperm15_1", 
    "Endosperm15_2", "Endosperm20_1", "Endosperm20_2", "Inflorescence1", 
    "Inflorescence2", "Kernel1", "Kernel2", "Leaf1", "Leaf2", 
    "Root1", "Root2", "Root6DAS_1", "Root6DAS_2", "SAM_V1_1", 
    "SAM_V1_2", "SAM_V3_1", "SAM_V3_2", "Seedling1", "Seedling2", 
    "Seedling6DAS1", "Seedling6DAS2", "Stem1", "Stem2", "Tassel1", 
    "Tassel2", "Tassel1cm1", "Tassel1cm2", "TopLeaf1", "TopLeaf2"
    ), uORF.counts = c(0, 83.4955169709039, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28.7464807043411, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11.2406460145824, 0, 21.4246067462734, 
    3.79467228769529, 0, 15.7018825522203, 18.5389127807478, 
    0, 0, 27.5534687981229, 2.40281615863606, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 18.6624163966679, 0, 101.319692897418, 0, 18.1722085926888, 
    0, 0, 121.429685770491, 23.4813161069057), mORF.counts = c(2.78678991038632, 
    5.23135534859068, 0, 0, 0, 0.662658150794125, 0.409637837791766, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0729792711316374, 0.386564992374038, 
    0.534483728988032, 0, 1.37526811341663, 0.766753464638798, 
    0.485803306586024, 0, 0.607111227010591, 0.822436205751297, 
    0, 0, 0.621959939713711, 1.28140367859192, 0, 0, 0, 1.80538860963132, 
    0.532192947104563, 0.804098175333964, 1.09749529429666, 0, 
    0, 0.934978514834704, 1.40080302886771)), row.names = c(NA, 
-44L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), Zm00001eb000470_T001_2 = structure(list(
    uORF = c("Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_2"
    ), sample = c("1Leaf1", "1Leaf2", "1Root1", "1Root2", "3Leaf1", 
    "3Leaf2", "Ear1", "Ear2", "Ear5mm_1", "Ear5mm_2", "Embryo15_1", 
    "Embryo15_2", "Embryo20_1", "Embryo20_2", "Endosperm15_1", 
    "Endosperm15_2", "Endosperm20_1", "Endosperm20_2", "Inflorescence1", 
    "Inflorescence2", "Kernel1", "Kernel2", "Leaf1", "Leaf2", 
    "Root1", "Root2", "Root6DAS_1", "Root6DAS_2", "SAM_V1_1", 
    "SAM_V1_2", "SAM_V3_1", "SAM_V3_2", "Seedling1", "Seedling2", 
    "Seedling6DAS1", "Seedling6DAS2", "Stem1", "Stem2", "Tassel1", 
    "Tassel2", "Tassel1cm1", "Tassel1cm2", "TopLeaf1", "TopLeaf2"
    ), uORF.counts = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25.7804563635811, 0), mORF.counts = c(2.78678991038632, 
    5.23135534859068, 0, 0, 0, 0.662658150794125, 0.409637837791766, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0729792711316374, 0.386564992374038, 
    0.534483728988032, 0, 1.37526811341663, 0.766753464638798, 
    0.485803306586024, 0, 0.607111227010591, 0.822436205751297, 
    0, 0, 0.621959939713711, 1.28140367859192, 0, 0, 0, 1.80538860963132, 
    0.532192947104563, 0.804098175333964, 1.09749529429666, 0, 
    0, 0.934978514834704, 1.40080302886771)), row.names = c(NA, 
-44L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), Zm00001eb000470_T001_3 = structure(list(
    uORF = c("Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_3"
    ), sample = c("1Leaf1", "1Leaf2", "1Root1", "1Root2", "3Leaf1", 
    "3Leaf2", "Ear1", "Ear2", "Ear5mm_1", "Ear5mm_2", "Embryo15_1", 
    "Embryo15_2", "Embryo20_1", "Embryo20_2", "Endosperm15_1", 
    "Endosperm15_2", "Endosperm20_1", "Endosperm20_2", "Inflorescence1", 
    "Inflorescence2", "Kernel1", "Kernel2", "Leaf1", "Leaf2", 
    "Root1", "Root2", "Root6DAS_1", "Root6DAS_2", "SAM_V1_1", 
    "SAM_V1_2", "SAM_V3_1", "SAM_V3_2", "Seedling1", "Seedling2", 
    "Seedling6DAS1", "Seedling6DAS2", "Stem1", "Stem2", "Tassel1", 
    "Tassel2", "Tassel1cm1", "Tassel1cm2", "TopLeaf1", "TopLeaf2"
    ), uORF.counts = c(0, 147.722837717753, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 50.8591581692189, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19.8872967950304, 0, 54.1501049631087, 
    6.71365097053781, 0, 27.7802537462358, 32.7996149197846, 
    0, 0, 64.9979263955721, 4.25113628066379, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 33.0181213171818, 14.1747578900174, 179.257918203124, 
    15.7804228950156, 85.7355482321728, 0, 0, 214.837136363176, 
    49.852640350046), mORF.counts = c(2.78678991038632, 5.23135534859068, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.662658150794125, 0.409637837791766, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0729792711316374, 0.386564992374038, 
    0.534483728988032, 0, 1.37526811341663, 0.766753464638798, 
    0.485803306586024, 0, 0.607111227010591, 0.822436205751297, 
    0, 0, 0.621959939713711, 1.28140367859192, 0, 0, 0, 1.80538860963132, 
    0.532192947104563, 0.804098175333964, 1.09749529429666, 0, 
    0, 0.934978514834704, 1.40080302886771)), row.names = c(NA, 
-44L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), Zm00001eb000470_T001_4 = structure(list(
    uORF = c("Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", 
    "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4", "Zm00001eb000470_T001_4"
    ), sample = c("1Leaf1", "1Leaf2", "1Root1", "1Root2", "3Leaf1", 
    "3Leaf2", "Ear1", "Ear2", "Ear5mm_1", "Ear5mm_2", "Embryo15_1", 
    "Embryo15_2", "Embryo20_1", "Embryo20_2", "Endosperm15_1", 
    "Endosperm15_2", "Endosperm20_1", "Endosperm20_2", "Inflorescence1", 
    "Inflorescence2", "Kernel1", "Kernel2", "Leaf1", "Leaf2", 
    "Root1", "Root2", "Root6DAS_1", "Root6DAS_2", "SAM_V1_1", 
    "SAM_V1_2", "SAM_V3_1", "SAM_V3_2", "Seedling1", "Seedling2", 
    "Seedling6DAS1", "Seedling6DAS2", "Stem1", "Stem2", "Tassel1", 
    "Tassel2", "Tassel1cm1", "Tassel1cm2", "TopLeaf1", "TopLeaf2"
    ), uORF.counts = c(0, 125.243275456356, 0, 0, 0, 0, 41.8068094051703, 
    45.9943691269458, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.06065810661049, 
    3.79467228769529, 0, 0, 0, 144.251178847067, 0, 36.7379583974973, 
    4.80563231727211, 11.8552123025014, 0, 0, 190.042200283117, 
    0, 0, 24.8832218622239, 52.0768279002814, 55.2652870349554, 
    8.91936946240015, 24.2296114569184, 0, 0, 14.5715622924589, 
    4.69626322138114), mORF.counts = c(2.78678991038632, 5.23135534859068, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.662658150794125, 0.409637837791766, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0729792711316374, 0.386564992374038, 
    0.534483728988032, 0, 1.37526811341663, 0.766753464638798, 
    0.485803306586024, 0, 0.607111227010591, 0.822436205751297, 
    0, 0, 0.621959939713711, 1.28140367859192, 0, 0, 0, 1.80538860963132, 
    0.532192947104563, 0.804098175333964, 1.09749529429666, 0, 
    0, 0.934978514834704, 1.40080302886771)), row.names = c(NA, 
-44L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

This is the code I am using to generate the scatterplot:

```
plots <-
  big_list2 |>
  map(\(x) ggplot(x, aes(x = uORF.counts, y = mORF.counts, label = sample, main = x[[1]][[1]][1])) +  
        geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = lm) + geom_text(hjust=0, vjust=0) +
        labs(x = "Counts in uORF (TPM)", y ="Counts in mORF (TPM)"))
```

It would also be useful to save the plot with the transcript name in the filename. Currently, it is saving them based on their standing in the list.

This is the code for that:

```
map2(plots, paste("plot", 1:length(plots)), \(x, y) ggsave(paste0(y, ".png"), plot = x))
```

Comment: You say a scatterplot, but fail to mention what you are plotting. What columns provide the `x` and `y` coordinates?

Comment: I apologize. I just added the code I am using to generate the scatterplot.

Comment: No problem, my answer should still apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

p <- imap(big_list2, ~ ggplot(.x, aes(uORF.counts, mORF.counts)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(.y))
iwalk(p, ~ ggsave(paste0(.y, ".png"), plot = .x))

p[[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Hello LMc, is ".y" the index of the list element? Thanks

Comment: Close -- `.y` is the *name* of the list element.